# Twebconnection method not allowed error windows server 2008 R2

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have a Delphi application server that I installed on `windows server 2008 R2`
I have registered the dcom object in windows component services.

when I connect to the app server via tsocketconnection i can connect fine no problems whatsoever, and my client application runs fine.
When I try connect to the application server via Twebconnection,
 I get a error :
`"method not allowed error"`
I have added a scripts virtual directory in `iis 7.5` and added `httpsrvr.dll` into that directory

But still cant get it to connect from the client.

Comment: is this a DataSnap question?

Comment: Yes it is , it was originally written in d7 and recompiled using xe

Comment: AFAIK 2008R2 is 64-bit only, are you sure it could run httpsrvr.dll which AFAIK is 32-bit only? Did you check the event log for more informations? Anyway that kind of DCOM proxy is no longer supported, IMHO it's time you inspect alternatives.